# A circumflex in PHP meaning

Tags: php

I have an issue where the following code returns a A with a little ^ before the £'s

This only happens on the smartphone site I'm building in query mobile - fine on the desktop site.
Can someone explain, and show me how to get rid of it?

thanks

```
      <h1 class="priceCntr"><span class="price">£<?php echo $row_rs_dealsother['cost']; ?></span><span class="costold"> WAS £<?php echo $row_rs_dealsother['costold']; ?></span></h1>
```

Comment: That's an encoding issue. I would use `&pound;` just to have it work generally.

Comment: You're probably looking at a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Show us your js. By the way ^ is in PHP the xor operator.

Comment: Have you set the document encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the encoded version:

```
&pound;
```

In your case:

```
 <h1 class="priceCntr"><span class="price">&pound;<?php echo $row_rs_dealsother['cost']; ?></span><span class="costold"> WAS &pound;<?php echo $row_rs_dealsother['costold']; ?></span></h1>
```